# Fetching data in script setup with vue-router

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

Has anyone tried fetch data from `script setup` using router? I think the problem is when script setup compiles to `async setup`.
This is the template of my main router component:

```html
<RouterView v-slot="{ Component }">
    <KeepAlive max="1">
        <component :is="Component" v-bind="props" />
    </KeepAlive>
</RouterView>
```

Example template:

```js
<template>
  <p>{{ JSON.stringify(data) }}</p>
</template>
<script setup>
const data = await fetchData();
</script>
```

If use an async function the component doesn't render and I get the following error:
`Component <Anonymous>: setup function returned a promise, but no <Suspense> boundary was found in the parent component tree. A component with async setup() must be nested in a <Suspense> in order to be rendered.`

I then modified my main template as follows:

```html
<RouterView v-slot="{ Component }">
    <KeepAlive max="1" include="CompletePage">
        <Suspense timeout="0">
            <template #default>
                <component :is="Component" v-bind="props" />
            </template>
        </Suspense>
    </KeepAlive>
</RouterView>
```

The component now renders, but I am also getting a new warning printed to console:
`[Vue warn]: <Suspense> slots expect a single root node`
along with the following message:
`<Suspense> is an experimental feature and its API will likely change.`

What is the best way to fetch data from `<script setup>`? Is there something else I am overlooking here? Another option maybe?
And if `Suspense` is an experimental feature, why does the engine force me to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I usually fetch data from my main `<script setup>`, but I don't have that problem.
My current code is:

```js
// main.ts

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);

router.isReady().then(() => {
    app.mount("#app");
});
```

```html
<!-- app.vue -->

<template>
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <Suspense>
      <component :is="Component" />
    </Suspense>
  </router-view>
</template>
```

```html
<!-- somepage.vue -->

<template>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ someData }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  const someData = ref([]);

  someData.value = await fetchSomeData();
</script>
```

Does this work for you?